# Check if one of all variables is empty

Tags: python, variables

```
def ask():
    global name, loca

    print "What's your name?"
    name = raw_input('> ')
    print "Where are you from?"
    loca = raw_input('> ')

    if name or loca == None:
        print "Please enter valid details."
        ask()

ask()
print "Alright, so you're " + name + ", from " + loca + "."
```

With this script, it will only ever print the last line if both of my variables are empty. If I fill in one, or both, it triggers that `if`, making me redo the function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: could you state more clearly your termination condition, ie how do you want to indicate that the program should end? Or should it ask only once? (Also, did you mean to use recursion here?)

Comment: It should print the last line if both variables have a value, if one or more don't have a value then it will re-ask the user to enter both variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have very well isolated the problem:

```
if name or loca == None:
```

Here you think it says:

```
"If either name or loca equal none:"
```

But instead it says:

```
"if (name) is true or (loca equals None) is true:"
```

Where it should say:

```
"if (name equals none) is true or (loca equals none) is true:"
```

Which is:

```
if name is None or loca is None:
```

See, by the way, that None comparisons are better carried out with `is`, since there is only one `None` object.

Also, a more pythonic way of doing it is:

```
if not all((name, loca)):
```

Or, seeing as "all" it's just 2 variables:

```
if not (name and loca):
```

If you don't understand, read around a bit (the Python tutorial is excellent -- go for the conditionals part). Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
if not all([name, loca]):
   print "Please enter valid details"
   ask()
```

Comment: Note that if any of those are the empty string (or any false-y value) this will also not pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

Well, neither `name` nor `loca` can ever be `None` after running `ask()`. At worst they're empty strings: `''`. What you're doing is asking if `name` is `True`, which it is if `name` has any value *other* than `''`.

What you want to do is check if the names have a non-empty value:

```
if not (name and loca):
    …
```

should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
if name or loca == None:
```

This will never trigger for two reasons:

1. First, if you don't enter any data, you get an empty string, not `None`, so `loca == None` will *never* be true.
2. Second, your `if` statement is checking two things: whether `name` is truthy (contains any data), and whether `loca == None`. You probably meant `if name == None or loca == None`.

Combining these two things, you can write:

```
if name == "" or loca == "":
```

Or, simplifying and taking advantage of the fact that strings are "truthy" if they contain data:

```
if not (name and loca):
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into your code to get the behavior you are looking for:

```
if not name or not loca:
    print "Please enter valid details."
    ask()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(field is None for field in (name, loca)):
    print "Please enter valid details."
    ask()
```

This version is specifically to allow the empty string, but prevent `None`, and allows you to extend it easier than an `and` or `or`.  It does mean typing a few more characters, though.

A nice perk is that this almost reads like proper english:  If any field is None...